# Having trouble with UTF-8 storing in NVarChar in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, utf-8, utf-16

I'm pulling data using `System.Net.WebClient` from a web site, and when the data comes back everything parses and looks good except letters with accents. For example, when it returns an `é`, SQL Server 2008 saves it as `Ã©`.

Just need to figure out how to convert these UTF-8 characters into something SQL Server can read. I'm storing it in an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` datatype.

I'm using Linq-to-SQL to insert into the database if you were curious.

Any thoughts on what I could do to convert it to the proper format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out!  When using the WebClient class, I was downloading the data as a string.

My Original Configuration...

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string htmlData = wc.DownloadString(myUri);
```

I tried to convert this data into a UTF-16...from it's current string, but since Microsoft operates in UTF-16, it had handled the conversion on its own.

Instead, I switched my approach to reading the actual byte[] array from the data like so...

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string htmlData = UTFConvert(wc.DownloadData(myUri));

private string UTFConvert(byte[] utfBytes)
{
    byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, utfBytes);
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(isoBytes);
}
```

This fixed the problem, and SQL correctly see's the accents in everything now.  Yippee.

Cheers all, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Every string in .NET is already UTF-16, so "converting" it into UTF-16 is nonsense. For "globalized" (localized!) systems this is also the most sensible choice. Maybe MSSQL should support UTF-8 natively, but I've found using varchar instead of nvarchar with the appropriate collation works well enough for "western language only" systems.

Answer (score 3):

[Description of storing UTF-8 data in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580). There is also a discussion of this topic at [International Features in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). the gist of it is: SQL Server has no support for UTF-8. Feel free to upvote the request to [Add support for storing UTF-8 natively in SQL Server](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/362867/add-support-for-storing-utf-8-natively-in-sql-server).

As a note though, since you store Unicode string via LINQ, this would point that the problem occurs *before* writing into SQL Server. Namely your web pulling, does it appropriately convert the data read using an UTF-8 reader? Namely, do you read the [`WebResponse.GetResponseStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) via a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx) constructed with the appropriate [`UTF8Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx)? That *should* create the proper Unicode string and then the NVARCHAR storage in the DB (which is UCS-2) should be fine.

Comment: Even if SQL supported it though, the value will get mangled by C#'s utf-16 strings won't it? That has been my experience with downloading web content in C#. In the end I work through the byte[] stream of the response and replace all the high-order characters with their HTML escape codes.

Comment: @Chris: If you use the properly configured StreamReader no character should be mangled at all. The Encoding with which the reader is constructed must match the actual response (page) encoding.

Comment: Great, this helped.  I have exactly the code I used to fix it.  I got the response stream via the WebClient (in a byte[] array).  Then I just ran an automatic UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion on the byte[] array to return a proper string.    I'll post the exact code tomorrow when I'm allowed to post an 'answer'.  Thanks for your help @Remus