# ASP.NET WebForms page is partially Encoding Gibberish.

Tags: asp.net, .net, encoding, master-pages, content-pages

i have a webform.page, on a master.page.

1. When I run from VS Development Server, everything looks great... hebrew and stuff :")
2. When I deploy/upload the files to 'Arvixe.com' shared server.
   the page comes half gibberish.
3. The content of the Master.Page is kept intact.
4. The content of the Web-form is Gibberish, EXCEPT for text that come from my SQL DATABASE as NVARCHAR.

There are slight differences in the Web.config (other constraints).
tried playing with `<globalization>` tag.
all pages contain 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Screenshot - only the Title of the Repeater is hardcoded in the content page
[image: Screenshot - only the Title of the Repeater is hardcoded in the content page]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble with UTF-8 storing in NVarChar in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723238/having-trouble-with-utf-8-storing-in-nvarchar-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: it aint the SQL problem, found the solution see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Typical...
spend 2 hours searching for the solution.
another 15 min to phrase the question.
and find the solution 2 min after that.

the Content Pages where ANSI so i converted them to UTF8 and uploaded.
Everything is great now both locally, and on the server.

Comment: what i dont understand is : why did it work locally on VS Development Server?

Comment: By "VS Development server" do you mean SQL Server express, or are you talking about the IIS Express?

Comment: SQL 2008R2 Std, with the Visual Studio Built-in Server